# How to reduce the code to one line or output it to a function?

Tags: c#

Good afternoon! I have a code that checks the value of three constants

```cs
var postgres =
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgSQLRegKey + Constants.BID, true) ??
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgSQLRegKey + Constants.CID, true) ??
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgSQLRegKey + Constants.FID, true);
```

Is it possible to write it in one line or a separate function?

To avoid writing three times

```cs
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgreSQLRegKey)
```

Comment: It is one line already. You can definitely move to a function to encapsulate the long line, which appears to require 0 input arguments and a single output value.

Comment: in more detail, you can how to make a separate function so that you do not write three times

Comment: `RegistryKey` is `IDisposable` - so you need `using` statements.

Comment: @Dai: True, but *one* `using` statement suffices, since `??` stops as soon as the first non-null RegistryKey is returned.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
Func<string, RegistryKey?> openSubKey = (c) => 
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgreSQLRegKey + c, true);

var postgresServicesKeyNew =
    openSubKey(Constants.BID) ??
    openSubKey(Constants.CID) ??
    openSubKey(Constants.FID);
```

This is generally how you could refactor this to reduce the duplication.

Comment: This. I'd probably use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) instead of a lambda, but that's just a matter of style.

Comment: @Heinzi Don't forget `static` local functions: which never create a closure or capture local variables so you can be sure you're not inadvertently causing unnecessary GC heap allocs.

Comment: The code in this answer performs _runtime_ string concatenation when the `Constants.BID/CID/FID` strings are concated to `Constants.PostgreSQLRegKey` inside `openSubKey`. The performance impact is absolutely negligible, but if you _really_ wanted to improve this code for some reason then I suggest using compile-time concatenation inside each `openSubKey` call-site, but using a `using C = Constants` alias for succinctness, e.g. `openSubKey( C.PostgreSQLRegKey + C.BID ) ?? openSubKey( C.PostgreSQLRegKey + C.CID ) ?? openSubKey( C.PostgreSQLRegKey + C.FID )`

Comment: @Dai could you declare another constant referring to `const string r = C.PostgreSQLRegKey;` to reduce it even further and still get the compile-time optimisations? i.e. `openSubKey(r+C.BID)` etc.

Comment: @phuzi There is zero reason to declare a new constant like that. The `Constants` class is already in-scope.

Comment: @Dai Would make the invocation even shorter! But you're certainly reducing readability.

Comment: @phuzi Yes, but you're introducing a new `string` constant field into your compiled assembly that's just going to sit there and do nothing - and leave future maintainers scratching their heads. (**UPDATE:** Sorry, I thought you meant to introduce `r` as a `const` field, not as a `const` local - so I think that should be sufficiently zero-overhead, yes.

Comment: @phuzi I've posted my own answer just now.

Answer (score 3):

Chipping in my own take:

```cs
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    using static Constants; // <-- This brings `PostgreSQLRegKey`, `CID`, `BID`, and `FID` into scope without further qualification.

    public class MyClass
    {
        void Foobar()
        {
            // This is a static-local function, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/static-local-functions
            // Named "ow" for "open-writable" - or "ow!" because you're messing around in the Registry which you probably shouldn't be 
            static RegistryKey? ow( String keyPath )
            {
                return Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( name: keyPath, writable: true );
            }

            const String P = PostgreSQLRegKey;

            using( RegistryKey? reg = ow( P + BID ) ?? ow( P + CID ) ?? ow( P + FID ) )
            {
                if( reg != null )
                {
                    // do stuff?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, taking it to the extreme :o)

Answer (score -3):

Looking at the previous solution there is still repetition I will go with this

```
const openSubKey = (c) => {
      return Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgreSQLRegKey + Constants.c, true);
      }

let postgresServicesKeyNew = 
openSubKey(BID)??
openSubKey(CID)??
openSubKey(FID);
```

This is how I refactor this code to avoid writing constants repeatedly

Comment: `Constants.c` Uh, no, that won't work. And C# won't allow you to use `let` at that position. And you're missing semicolons. Is is possible that your answer targets a different programming language?

Comment: I don't quite understand how to pass Constants.BID values in (c)
Func<string, RegistryKey?> openSubKey = (c) =>
     Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Constants.PostgreSQLRegKey + c, true);
var postgresServicesKeyNew =
     openSubKey(Constants.BID) ??
     openSubKey(Constants.CID) ??
     openSubKey(Constants.FID);

Can you explain this snippet in more detail

Comment: It's not C# language, constructs you are proposing will not compile. You can do similar thing in C# with local functions but that's what's already proposed